# How to catch a non-ASCII character error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I am trying to catch this error `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3'` using this code:

```
try:
    address = 'ÁR11E'
except:
    print 'hello'
```

I can never get "hello" printed. The error is treated as unhandled and stops the process. How can I catch and handle this type of error?

I only have to catch the error without solving it for now.

Comment: The SyntaxError is thrown by the compiler compiling your code, before any of it gets to run, so you can't handle it. (Well, you _could_ handle it by installing an import hook, but that's not trivial, and there's not much good you could do there, so…).

Comment: General communications principle: Text files use a character encoding. Programs that read text files must know what it is. If you are writing for a program, find out either what it expects or what it can accept and how to tell it what you are giving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Python 2 source code should contain only ASCII characters, therefore this is syntax error. You cannot catch it, because it makes the whole file invalid.

There are two things you can do:

- [change the code page](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) of the fie from ASCII to something else:

`# coding: utf-8`

- or encode the non-ascii character

`address = '\xC3\x81R11E'  # this would be utf-8`

`address = '\xC3\x81R11E'.decode('utf-8')  # this would be unicode`

or

`address = u'\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE}R11E'`

or

`address = u'\u0381R11E'`

Comment: Do I have to encode the character before running the script or within the script?

Comment: In my case, I have to pass a string containing the character to python script as an argument. Is it possible to encode the argument at the very beginning of python process?

Comment: @zhangjinzhou You only have this problem when writing the string into the script itself. Reading it from console, or from a file and passing it around is no problem. Python can handle all of it, it just does not let you enter it into the source code without specifying the encoding, to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: It may be worth saying "python 2 source code", because 3.x defaults to UTF-8 instead of ASCII. (I don't think you need to explain the Python 3 situation, or look up whether the UTF-8 default goes all the way back to 3.0 or came later, etc., since the question is explicitly about 2.7; just saying "python 2" should be enough.)

Comment: @abarnert You are right, I updated the answer to make that clear.

Comment: Also, it might be worth mentioning the `\u0381` escape. While the `\N` is definitely clearer and easier to understand, it can get a bit verbose, and `u'\u0381'` is still nicer than `'\xc3\x81'.decode('utf-8')` for people who don't want to get that verbose.

Comment: Thank you guys. We are making progress. Is there a way to check if the input arguments include any no-ascii character at first? If it does, encode the character, for example Á as \xc3 and then do rest of process?

Comment: @zhangjinzhou What kind of "Input arguments" are you talking about? The strings in `sys.argv`, or the result of a `raw_input` call, or …? At any rate, non-ASCII characters in string values, rather than in your source code, aren't SyntaxErrors, so you don't have the same problem—but you do generally want to `decode` those strings using the appropriate encoding. For example, if you're using `raw_input`, something like `name = raw_input('Please enter your name: ').decode('utf-8')` will make sure you safely get their name in Unicode (assuming your console is actually UTF-8, at least).

Comment: I meant sys.argv. I will try the method you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot catch a syntax error in Python (except if it is raised from an eval, which is not your case)

Comment: You can catch it when importing a module, as well.

Answer (score 1):

1st line (linux)

## !usr/bin/env python

2nd line (linux)

## coding: utf-8

Comment: You should always write a short explanation. Remember others will see your answers in the future and seeing an explaination of why you did something will help. :)